# How to create always-top fullscreen overlay activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, window

I'd like to be able to create an Activity that is always at the front of display of Android.
It should receive no input, just pass it down to whatever application is next below it. Something like a HUD.

I was able to research that I need to set underlying window type to TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT but it looks like Android is ignoring my code - no exception thrown even if I delete android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission from manifest. (it is required to use this window type). When I tried to use ALERT type on dialog, it worked OK, but I cannot make dialog into full screen transparent entity.
Here is my code, maybe there is something simple missing.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);             
     getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
     getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Translucent setting has to be enabled externally in xml manifest, otherwise it also didn't work.

```
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Comment: what about for oreo

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) App.inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
wm.addView(mTopView, params);
```

Comment: What did your onCreate method end up looking like? I'm trying to test this myself now.

Comment: ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) App.inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
@tmouse what is APP here ?

Comment: @tmouse what is R.layout.main? is it the activity layout? or a filler view transparent?

Comment: @ rana use getLayoutInflater() instead

Comment: Note that this is a window rather than an activity.

Comment: How to use finish() here. It is not closing with finish() method

Answer (score 5):

I found that [the accepted answer (by tmouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095344/how-to-create-always-top-fullscreen-overlay-activity-in-android/10107525#10107525) did not quite work for me. Maybe it worked for an older API level? I'm using API level 24.

That particular answer had recommended:

```java
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);
```

There is a problem with this. The constructors that exist for `WindowManager.LayoutParams` are as follows:

[image]

So the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN` flag gets used as an *explicit value for `int w` and `int h`*. This is no good! Your view's dimensions get set to 1024*1024 — so it does not *fill* the screen. And even if you *explicitly* set the layout's width and height to match the device's dimensions: they will **not** update when the screen orientation changes. We need a different approach…

---

I found that the *correct* construction for a full-screen overlay is like so:

```java
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, // TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT is denied in apiLevel >=19
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);
```

This means we no longer *explicitly* specify a width and height. The layout relies entirely on our flags instead.

Yes, `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN` is a required flag still; it is necessary if you want to draw over decorations such as the status bar.

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` should be used instead of `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` in API level >=19. This is a note I wrote a while ago, sadly I've been unable to find citation to corroborate why I thought that, so take that with a pinch of salt.

---

Bonus notes (if you're reading this, you're probably trying to make a full-screen overlay):

Your manifest will need these permissions (explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34061521/5257399)):

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

My understanding is that `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` is the actual permission required, but that `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` is needed also: it lets you request at runtime that the user grant the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` privilege.

I provide [here](https://github.com/Birch-san/touhou-walk) the source code to my working API level 24 app that creates a full-screen overlay.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this

mention it in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

if you want to make your Activity full screen and transparent also

check out this

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but what above achieves is only setting up activity as fulscreen/transparent. What I'm trying to do is to make activity ALWAYS on top, regardless of what user is doing (launching other applications, locking phone, etc).

Comment: did you used  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"></uses-permission>` in Manifest file if not check out this

Comment: Yes, as I've written I've used this but as above code is executed this permission is never used (which is wrong - permission is required for such a window to appear).