# Creating a transparent pass-through activity

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095344/how-to-create-always-top-fullscreen-overlay-activity-in-android). So, far no luck. I used his code, but I'm not able to get past this error..I'm not familiar with inflaters. So could someone explain this code?

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) getApplicationContext()
            .getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_invisible, null);
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    wm.addView(mTopView, params);
```

This part of the code:

```
ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) getApplicationContext()
            .getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_invisible, null);
```

Gives me this error `The method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the type Context`

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you try to execute this code?

Comment: `onCreate()` method itself.

Comment: probably because there is no getLayoutInflater() method in a context. try to use your activity, for instance. or, like you do above, getSystemService

Comment: i don't even get why you bother calling getSystemService if you are not going to use that layoutinflater anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getLayoutInflater()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLayoutInflater%28%29) is a method in [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), not [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

You must be using an instance of an Activity to call it, or else it will not work.

However, you can probably use the LayoutInflater `inflater` you create on the line before the one with the error. Something like:

```
ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_invisible, null);
```

Comment: The thing is the link that I've posted in my question uses application context. Or so, I think. Could you check that please? Because his code is `ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) App.inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);`

What exactly could `App` be?

Comment: App is likely he name of his Application class. `inflater` is most likely a static LayoutInflater object that he initializes in the onCreate() of his Application class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to execute this code inside `onCreate()`, instead of

```
ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) getApplicationContext().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_invisible, null);
```

try

```
ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_invisible, null);
```

Your activity has the `getLayoutInflater()` method, so there's no need to obtain context explicitly.